# Как определить момент сохранения файла .xls в библиотеке PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Есть функция - в которой используя библиотеку PHPExcel, формируется таблица и автоматически сохраняется браузером. Таблица на сервере формируется какое-то время которое сопровождается прелодером. Как получить событие завершения скачивания файла?

```
        $xls = new PHPExcel();
        $xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->fromArray(array_keys($result[0]),NULL,'A1');
        $sheet->fromArray($result,NULL,'A2');
        
        header("Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT");
        header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_SESSION['title_menu'] . '_'.date("Y-m-d").".xlsx");
    
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xls, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        $xls->disconnectWorksheets();
        die();
```

Comment: Нужно узнать о завершении скачивания файла на стороне пользователя? Или о том, что файл сформировался на сервере?

Comment: Нужно узнать на стороне пользователя. В идеале - я хочу получить какое-нибудь событие( момент завершения скачивания файла браузером ) - чтобы к нему я смог прицепить нужную мне функцию.